# Can a chain with repeated nodes still be considered a Markov chain?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

The well-known Markov Property is that $$P(X_n = i | X_{n-1} = k_1, \dots, X_{n-j} = k_n ) = P(X_n = i | X_{n-1} = k_1) $$

Suppose we lay out some stochastic model in the following transition probability graph

[image]

Given that there is a repeated, node, is it still possible to consider the process a Discrete Time Markov chain?

Comment: Why not merge the two nodes called 1, to one and same node?

Comment: In this spirit, I could also merge the node 1 (lower) and 3 into a single node, is that right?

Comment: Actually yes, but then the picture will not correspond to the story behind it. You should then also change the probability 0.2 from 2 to 1 (upper) to 0.2+0.2=0.4. Or you could name the 1 (lower) to 4 and have again a Markov-Chain, or not?

Comment: Ignoring the issue of two nodes with the same label, that is a Markov Chain.  Indeed it is an ergodic Markov Chain.  And the two nodes labelled $1$ are different: one leads directly to node $2$ while the other does not.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you right down a definition of your stochastic process as such a graph, you force it to be a Markov Chain (MC), at least if the graph is given its usual interpretation. But in that case you consider every node to be a separate state, so that the "1" below would be a state different from the top-left "1". We call that Labeled MCs: whereas an MC is given by a pair $(X,P)$ where $X$ is the state space and $P$ is a transition matrix, an LMC is a tuple $(X,P,Y,L)$ where $Y$ is a set of labels and $L:X\to Y$ is a labeling map. For example, in your case $X = (a,a',b,c)$, $P$ is given by your graph, $Y = (1,2,3)$ and $L:(a,a',b,c)\mapsto(1,1,2,3)$. It happens that $X$ is indeed an MC (by definition), that is it satisfies Markov property. It induces a stochastic process on $Y$, which in this case is not  a Markov process: given that $Y = 1$ you have different probabilities depending on whether you know the whole history, or just the current label.